# Android runOnUiThread() not updating TextView

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, textview

So I know that this question has come up before, but I cannot find what is going wrong with my code. I have a TextView that I want to update and a Button that I want to make invisible just so I can see that it is working. In my onCreate I have:

```
setMessage("Welcome, " + pref.getString("fName", "User"));
```

which calls to the method I created:

```
private void setMessage(final String input)
{
    this.input = input;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            message.setText(input);
            create.setVisibility(4);
        }
    });
    Toast.makeText(this, input, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The toast is just so that I can see that the string comes out correctly, and it does. I get no crashes, no errors in the log, nothing. The Textview is set to a string in my Strings.xml that says "Hello World!" and after the activity starts it reads that message, but the button is still visible and the message that comes up for toast doesn't come up. What am I doing wrong? Input is a String by the way.

My variables:

```
private TextView message;
private Button create;
private SharedPreferences pref;
private int norecurs = 0;
private Bundle state;
private Handler handler;
private String input;
```

All my code in onCreate() that wasn't there before:

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("login", 0);
    message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    input = "Welcome, " + pref.getString("fName", "User");
    setMessage("Welcome, " + pref.getString("fName", "User"));
```

Comment: First of all, I would highly recommend using the constant, `View.INVISIBLE` instead of the `int`. Second, you don't need `runOnUiThread()` if you are calling it from `onCreate()` as it will already run on the main thread.

Comment: Show the code where you are actually making the call `setMessage("Welcome,....`. It looks like you're not even calling it since the Toast isn't coming up.

Comment: if you see the `Toast` that means you are already on the UI thread and `runOnUiThread` is not needed

Comment: But it doesn't update the TextView either way, I only added the runOnUiThread() because I was under the impression that it would update the text.

Comment: The toast is coming up, and with the String I want the TextView to have

Comment: post the code where you find and affect `message`

Comment: remove the `runOnUiThread()` and see what happens and we can go from there. Either way, that isn't needed here.

Comment: I tried putting the setText() directly back into onCreate, no dice. Updated code in the question.

Comment: @dburnsii Do you need to process the input in any way? I will try and provide an answer for you, but I'm not sure what it is you're trying to achieve

Comment: Not really. Input is just an arbitrary name I used (I would have went with "message" but that's the TextView name) and once it runs through onCreate() it's ready. Just, for whatever reason it doesn't update the TextView when I call .setText() and I can't figure out, whether its in onCreate or runOnUiThread.

Comment: @dburnsii I have provided an answer below for you-- hopefully it should clarify what the people above are trying to say.

Comment: No no I'd much rather get rid of it if its unnecessary, I just want to know what I'll need to do. I'm still trying fixes and took out `runOnUiThread()` as soon as you said I didn't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really seem like you need to create a new thread to be honest. Instead of:

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("login", 0);
message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
input = "Welcome, " + pref.getString("fName", "User");
setMessage("Welcome, " + pref.getString("fName", "User"));
```

You should write:

```
pref = getSharedPreferences("login", 0);
message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
create = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
input = "Welcome, " + pref.getString("fName", "User");

// Just set the text in your onCreate
message.setText("Welcome, " + pref.getString("fName", "User"));
```

If, however, you really want to keep the `setMessage` method, just change it to this:

```
private void setMessage(String input)
{
    this.input = input;

    message.setText(input);
    create.setVisibility(4);

    Toast.makeText(this, input, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I'm so confused. I have this code, except I put `input` inside the setText since it's the same String, and it doesn't change anything. I added another textview to set it and it doesn't update with `.setText()` either.

Comment: So it's still displaying "Hello, World!" ?

Comment: Yeah, and I've gone between using a string resource, using a string directly, and deleting `android:text=""` altogether, nothing seems to work. I do update both the activity xml and the fragment xml though, could that be an issue?

Comment: Okay, sorry to be a pain, but could you please edit you question to include: the whole of your Activity class, your activity XML file, and your fragment XML file please. I'm sure we can get to the bottom of it eventually :)

Comment: I think I figured it out actually. I had a nested `LinearLayout` within my `RelativeLayout` which I just changed to the former and, although its currently duplicating my layout it works!